# PHP http request vs curl

Tags: php, curl, request, captcha

I have this website where it's necessary to fill in a captcha code in order to proceed and get the information I need.

I was trying to use **php http request** to automate it on my php code by 'forwarding' the image to 'my' user and then get the capctha code to get that information. The idea is to redirect the captcha image on my php and keep the session, so after the user submit the captcha to my php it fills in the code to catch the information.

Basically, mirroring the captcha, no tricks, no cheats, no bypass.

But after some good struggle trying to make it work, it seems impossiple to get **php http request** running on the Blue hosting server. The error is always the same:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HttpRequest' not found
```

I tried reinstalling the modules and chosing different php.ini options as shown below. The error stills.

Now, is there any solution? Is there a way to catch the captcha image with curl and put it on my php, then get the user input and resume that remote session to get the info needed?

```
$r = new HttpRequest('http://example.com/feed.rss', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$r->setOptions(array('lastmodified' => filemtime('local.rss')));
$r->addQueryData(array('category' => 3));
try {
    $r->send();
    if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
        file_put_contents('local.rss', $r->getResponseBody());
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

[image: Blue Hosting php.ini settings]
[image: phph modules]

Comment: the extension might be installed, but did you check your php.ini to see if it's actually activated/loading? `phpinfo()` would tell you WHICH php file to check

Comment: here is the phpinfo(): http://ondocs.com.br/emitentes.php

Comment: besides, I tried to add these (http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php) lines to /usr/php/54/etc/php.ini but it is read only.